# Observable that behaves as BehaviorSubject(observable with default value)

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to combine latest values from 3 different streams ignoring that one(or more) of them that hasn't emit any value yet.

```
   const myStream1$:Observable<>=// steam from somewhere,
         myStream2$:Observable<string>=// steam from somewhere,
         myStream3$:Observable<string>=// steam from somewhere;

   Observable.combineLatest(myStream1$, myStream2$, myStream3$)
      .do(([valFromStream1, valFromStream2, valFromStream3])=>
    {
       // I want to do some side-effect operation even if one(or all) of those 3 streams hasn't emit any value yet
    })
    .takeUntil(terminator$)
    .subscribe();
```

How to achieve that?

I can achieve that using next logic(but it is as ugly as sh*t), I guess there should be an operator that does that auto-magically:

```
   const myStream1$:Observable<string>=// steam from somewhere,
         myStream2$:Observable<string>=// steam from somewhere,
         myStream3$:Observable<string>=// steam from somewhere;

   const subj1 = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined),
         subj2 = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined),
         subj3 = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined);

   myStream1$
      .do((val)=>{
      subj1.next(val);
    }).subscribe();

   myStream2$
      .do((val)=>{
      subj2.next(val);
    }).subscribe();

   myStream3$
      .do((val)=>{
      subj3.next(val);
    }).subscribe();

   Observable.combineLatest(subj1, subj2, subj3)
      .do(([valFromStream1, valFromStream2, valFromStream3])=>
    {
       // I want to do some side-effect operation even if one of those 3 streams hasn't emit any value yet
    })
    .takeUntil(terminator$)
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: you can use merge or flat map to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce combineLatest to emit by start each stream with a null value, then you can perform you logic conditionally base on whether the value is null

```
combineLatest(myStream1$.startWith(null),
myStream2$.startWith(null),
myStream3$.startWith(null))
.do(([v1,v2,v3])=>{
....
}).takeUntil(terminator$)
```

Comment: Got an error: ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: could you show me  the source code of the streams? or produce a simple stackbliz to demonstrate, since the code suppose to work.

Comment: Ok, it was my rookie mistake I was subscribing to value change of severals control and in *do* I was disabling/enabling them. Might be usefull for others:
https://angular-6ambrj.stackblitz.io